# Can't install vsftp and apt-get update 404 errors

Tags: apt

I'm trying to install vsftp on ubuntu 13.04 and am getting the following error:

```
nhudson@axum:~$ sudo apt-get install vsftpd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vsftpd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 112 kB of archives.
After this operation, 370 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  vsftpd
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main vsftpd amd64 3.0.2-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vsftpd/vsftpd_3.0.2-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried apt-get update with --fix-missing but that produced the same output as simple atp-get update:

```
nhudson@axum:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I get vsftp installed on my system?

Comment: After pointing to old-releases I get the following error:
`W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  502  notresolvable E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: I used the sed command from the other post and that produced the error above.  Now I changed `http://us.old-releases...` to `http://old-releases...` in the /etc/apt/sources.list and now I'm getting `W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  400  Bad Request`

Comment: Applying solution posted by Mikewhatever in [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Applying solution posted by Mikewhatever in [how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) resolved this issue (earlier posts in that thread did not).